# Java Stream multi list iteration

Tags: java, list, java-8, iteration, java-stream

I have 2 lists. 1 list is of Ids and the other list is full of `Foo` objects, call it list A. The `Foo` class looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String id;
    /* other member variables */

    Foo(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I have a plain list of ids like `List<Integer>`, call it list B. What I want to do is iterate over list B one element at a time, grab the id, compare it to list A and grab `Foo` object with the equivalent id and then add the `Foo` object to a new list, list C.

I'm trying to concatenate streams but I'm new to streams and I'm getting bogged down with all the methods like `map`, `filter`, `forEach`. I'm not sure what to use when.

Comment: You can put all Foo objects in a map with ID as key and then getting the Foo object by ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward way would be what you have in your post: loop over the ids, select the first `Foo` having that id and if one if found, collect it into a `List`. Put into code, it would look like the following: each id is mapped to the corresponding `Foo` that is found by calling [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) on the foos having that id. This returns an `Optional` that are filtered out it the `Foo` doesn't exist.

```
List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(new Foo("2"), new Foo("1"), new Foo("4"));

List<Foo> result =
    ids.stream()
       .map(id -> foos.stream().filter(foo -> foo.getId().equals(id.toString())).findFirst())
       .filter(Optional::isPresent)
       .map(Optional::get)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The big problem with this approach is that you need to traverse the `foos` list as many times as there are id to look. A better solution would first be to create a look-up `Map` where each id maps to the `Foo`:

```
Map<Integer, Foo> map = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> Integer.valueOf(f.getId()), f -> f));

List<Foo> result = ids.stream().map(map::get).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this case, we look-up the `Foo` and filter out `null` elements that means no `Foo` was found.

---

Another whole different approach is not to traverse the ids and search the `Foo`, but filter the `Foo`s having an id that is contained in the wanted list of ids. The problem with approach is that it requires to, then, sort the output list so that the order of the resulting list matches the order of the ids.

Comment: perfect. This is what I want. I realized I wasn't fully representing my scenario in my original post. My actual scenario is having 2 lists of Foo objects but the first list only has Foo objects with Ids but the other one has the full Foo objects with values for the other member variables. I wanted to compare them and retrieve the full foo objects. Your first solution worked perfectly! But I couldn't get the second one to work in my scenario

Comment: @Richard In the second snippet, if you don't have a list of id but a list of partial `Foo`, you first need to map each `Foo` to its id, something like `myPartialFoos.stream().map(Foo::getId).map(map::get) ...`

Comment: perfect again. Thanks for all the input!

Comment: In the first snippet, you can replace `.map(...findFirst()).filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)` with `.flatMap(...limit(1))`

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it like this :

```
List<Foo> list = Arrays.asList(
    new Foo("abc"),
    new Foo("def"),
    new Foo("ghi")
);

List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "xyz");

//Index Foo by ids
Map<String, Foo> map = list.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, Function.identity()));

//Iterate on ids, find the corresponding elements in the map
List<Foo> result = ids.stream().map(map::get)
  .filter(Objects::nonNull) //Optional...
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```